# Guard ArgumentNotNull - what is the argumentName parameter for?

Tags: c#, unity-container

In an MVC project we use Unity's Guard.ArgumentNotNull method to check for null parameters in the constructor. I think this is quite a common practise. Could anyone tell me what the second parameter - argumentName - in this method is for? Surely if the project compiles it means that the argument has been named correctly? I've tried changing this string name to something else and it doesn't throw an error.

`Guard.ArgumentNotNull(userRoleProvider, "userRoleProvider");`

Comment: I think this argument is for the internal exception that might be thrown in case of a null argument.

Comment: You might want to look into an upcoming language feature for C# 6, called `nameof()` - which eliminates the magic string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument is null then argumentName is passed into `ArgumentNullException` to indicate what the name of the offending (null) argument is.

There is no compiler (or runtime) impact to the name itself -- the argumentName string can be anything but in order to be meaningful (e.g. for troubleshooting) should be the actual name of the argument.